# Javascript show the loader icon while refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show the loader icon when the window is refreshing.And it should hide when the document is ready.What i have tried

//one solution

```
<script>
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
      setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById('interactive');
          document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

//another solution

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function WindowLoad() {
inst.close();
inst.destroy();
document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="block";
}
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
      setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('interactive');
    document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
      });
}
</script>
```

//style for loader- User Reference

```
<style>
#load{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position:fixed;
     z-index:9999;
     background:url("https://www.creditmutuel.fr/cmne/fr/banques/webservices/nswr/images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(129, 129, 131, 1)
 }
</style>
```

What i am getting?
I am getting the loader icon once after the page refresh is complete?I tried running both the solutions commenting each of the solutions.

Comment: where have you placed the loader div in html

Comment: `document` is ready *approximately* when the HTML is loaded. `window` is loaded when the images and other external resources are loaded. So depends on which way you want.

Comment: use this $('#load').fadeOut();

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/bartwal/pen/OXOoWN

Comment: The above solution works in the same way as that of my first solution.But for me loader icon should be displayed while browser itself is refreshed.It should stop when the document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here it is**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=8dda6cfac3ff590c6bcaed2bb2409b1b) Also you need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('loaderid').hide();
});
```

Make sure that the loader elements are just after the start of body tag.

Comment: If the page is taking a while to "load", it could be because of a lot of jquery document ready's - in which case, I'd also add a small `setTimeout` around the `.hide()` so it also waits for all the js/jquery to finish initialising.

Comment: Yes a smart idea.

Answer (score 0):

For non-jQuery approach.

1. Add some css to hide your div, e.g `mydiv { display:none; }`
2. After load, add/remove mydiv class from your div:

   document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove('mydiv');
   document.getElementById('div1').classList.add('mydiv');

Answer (score 0):

The loading div might show up late if you have placed it later in your HTML, you can try injecting the loading div as the first thing in the page before any other code.

```
<title>Smart Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.write('<div id="loading"><p><b>LOADING</b>...</p></div><style type="text/css">#loading{display:block; otherstyles..}</style>');
</script>
```

Use `window.load` if you want all resources including images to be loaded, or use `document.ready`. Its safer to keep this code at the end of the page just before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() { 
    $('#loading').fadeOut(500);
}); 

</script>
```